# Различия в результатах установки c помощью apt-get и dpkg -i

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

Имею возможность устанавливать пакеты (собственный продукт) двумя способами:

1. Скачать через `wget` и установить через `sudo dpkg -i package package-dependency`
2. Закинуть на cпециальный локальный ftp, где его подбирает демон apt-репозитория. Потом установить через `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install package;`

В чем существенные отличия этих двух вариантов? Второй всегда надежнее или могут быть обратные случаи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

программы вида *apt** (*apt*, *apt-get*, *aptitude*) — это, в первую очередь, средства работы с репозиториями: для скачивания индексов, расчёта зависимостей, скачивания файлов с пакетами.

непосредственно же для установки/удаления пакетов они вызывают программу *dpkg*.

---

если ваши пакеты (`package` и `package-dependency`) представлены ровно одной версией, являются архитектурно-независимыми, зависят **только** от тех пакетов (нужных версий), которые заведомо будут присутствовать в целевой системе, и при их установке заведомо не может возникнуть никаких конфликтов версий, то разницы между двумя приведёнными способами установки — нет.

во всех иных случаях — есть.

Comment: Могут ли быть случаи, когда правильнее или надёжнее будет установить через `dpkg`?

Comment: вообще-то, именно *установка* — она всегда происходит «через *dpkg*». а по существу: наверно, можно придумать такие обстоятельства, когда, при наличии доступа к корректно настроенному репозиторию, *правильнее и надёжнее* скачивать пакет(ы) «вручную», но мне в голову пока ничего не приходит.

Comment: вроде придумал такую ситуацию: когда пакет обновился, но разработчик не поставил новую версию. Тогда `apt-get` её пропустит.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я могу судить, разница между `apt-get install` и `dpkg` заключается, в частности в том, что команда `apt-get install` сама проверяет необходимые зависимости и устанавливает необходимые пакеты. Если Вы знаете, какие пакеты нужны для установки конечного, то разницы нет. По большому счету, утилита `apt-get install` является оберткой `dpkg`, и внутри себя обращается именно к ней. https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get/